# Antd `theme.defaultAlgorithm` is ignored

Tags: antd

I have setup Antd to use `theme.defaultAlgorithm` in the `<ConfigProvider/>` however it is ignored - it is still in dark mode. Inspecting the HTML it seems there is a selector `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` providing dark styles to the `:root` element. What is happening here? If I specify `theme.defaultAlgorithm` I don't want any dark styles.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is now fixed - the css was actually included the `globals.css` file that is within the vanilla nextjs install.